# In SQL Server, how to create a unique value column based on values of 2 other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016 Standard, how to create a column with a unique value based on the values of 2 other columns?

Please see below example to illustrate the question: I would like to create column 4 whereby an ascending numeric value is given to each matching `fabric_code` and `item_number` pair.

I.e. `fabric_code = '29989260'` and `item_number = '49002.01'` get the  `Unique_ID = '1'`

| fabric_code | item_number | doc_num | Unique_ID? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29989260 | 49002.01 | 1 | 1 |
| 29989260 | 49002.01 | 2 | 1 |
| 29989261 | 49002.02 | 1 | 2 |
| 29989261 | 49002.02 | 2 | 2 |
| 29989261 | 49002.02 | 3 | 2 |
| 29989262 | 49002.03 | 1 | 3 |

Ideally, I don't want to add a new column to the database, output using a `SELECT` statement would be what I'm after.

Comment: If you just want to add a column in the `SELECT`, why not define your expression there then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like

```
SELECT fabric_code, item_number, doc_number,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY fabric_code, item_number) Unique_ID
FROM YourTableName
```

You can read about [`dense_rank` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The idea is that the lowest `fabric_code`/`item_number` pair (all of them) should be 1, then the next lowest (all of them) will be 2, and so forth. You could change that numbering by adjusting the `order by` bit. Since it doesn't use `partition by` it won't reset the numbering for each group.

Comment: i think this may have cracked it, never heard of DENSE_RANK! just testing it now, looking at results

Comment: `DENSE_RANK()` is the way to go.

Comment: this solved the problem thank you, apologies i cannot cast vote yet, still being a newbie

Comment: A word of caution - this does exactly what's asked for; but the ID for a row won't persist between runs; i.e. if you deleted everything that currently has `Unique_ID = 1` then reran the statement you'd fine `Unique_ID = 1` shows up again - but now that ID's for everything that had previously ad `Unique_ID = 2`.  i.e. Don't treat this as a persisted ID.

Comment: Fair point, @JohnLBevan, although I think that will probably be true for any solution that generates the exact expected output in a one-off query. I guess the persistent alternative would be a hash of the two columns?

Comment: @EdmCoff - fully agree / yes a hash would be the only option there - just thought it worth mentioning as I can see this being something the unwary may not think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() along with partition by clause, with something like:

```
SELECT 
    fabric_code, item_number, doc_number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fabric_code, item_number 
                       ORDER BY doc_number) AS Unique_ID
FROM 
    YourTableName
```

Comment: wouldn't that not reproduce doc_num and you w

Comment: this just replicated what i have in the doc_num col